# Is It Possible to push file from one repo to another without initializing the second one locally?

Tags: git, github

I'm looking for solution, how can I push some files from my repo, to another, which I haven't initialize locally... for Example, I have created new Version of my API and I would like to push the files to backup store (which is the second repo), but is it possible to achieve this effect without making any changes to current one (like changing repo's url, and stuff like that)?

Comment: Note that you do not push *files*. You push *commits*. A Git repository is a holder-of-commits; `git push <remote> <refspec>...` tells your Git software to locate some commits in your repository, call up the given remote repository, offer them commits, and then ask them to set some *name* (or names) in their repository to remember the *latest* commit in your branch(es) as specified by your refspecs.

Comment: (Other than that, see [alb_pasqua's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73083714/1256452): you can add as many "remote" names as you like; `origin` is just the standard name for "the remote from which I cloned originally".)

Answer (score 0):

Yes,

you can add it as a remote:

```bash
git remote add <remote_repo_name> <remote_repo_address>
```

and then push to it:

```bash
git push <remote_repo_name>
```